# survey about the encoding techniques used in cloud computing

Tags: cloud, erasure-code

I am trying to perform a survey on the encoding techniques which can be applied to a file before storing it in the cloud. 
So far I have only encountered Reed Solomon erasure coding mechanism, in literature.

I am wondering if someone can point out to make if other techniques like rateless codes, which include LT codes or raptor codes can also be applied.

If anyone is aware of a survey conducted on the different encoding mechanisms, and if you can point me to this it will be great.

Thanks

Bhavya

Comment: What does this question have to do with "cloud computing"?  Are you assuming that "cloud" is less reliable than other forms of storage?

Comment: this question generally deals with file erasures and specifically deals with how file erasure storage is done in the cloud. Since I looking at it from a cloud perspective I was wondering if there is some literature which I was not aware of which explains erasure code being used before storing a file in the cloud

Answer (score 0):

please refer to the following surveys

http://web.eecs.utk.edu/~plank/plank/papers/2013-02-11-FAST-Bibliography.pdf

http://users.ece.utexas.edu/~dimakis/rc_Ieeeproc.pdf